# Optimization Intuition

Tags: calculus, optimization

Take this question for example:

What is the smallest possible sum of the squares of two numbers, $a$ and $b$, if $ab = -16$

So you get $b = \frac{-16}{a}$ and substitute.  Once you find your minimum value for $a$, you plug back into the original function, $ab = -16$ to get $b$.  Does this imply that $b = -4$ is a minimum value, too?  And if so, how does getting a minimum $a$ result in a minimum $b$?

Comment: Do you mean the original wire is of constant length, say $a$? Then the variable is where you cut it i.e. $x = $ the length of the first part. The second part has length $a-x$.

Comment: And I don't think you're minimizing the area of both shapes individually, but rather their total area.

Comment: @ploosu2: Yes, the original wire is of constant length, a.  Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: @Rahul: Oh yes, you are right.  That is my bad.  I will change the problem to better demonstrate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the more general problem of minimizing 
\begin{equation}
f = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation} subject to the constraint
\begin{equation}
ab = -k, k > 0.
\end{equation}

Rearranging the constraint, we can define $b$ in terms of $a$:
\begin{equation}
b = \frac{-k}{a}
\end{equation}

Substituting this into $f$, we now have a function of a single variable,
\begin{equation}
f = a^2 + \frac{k^2}{a^2}
\end{equation}

We can now apply standard optimization techniques to this function. First, find a derivative,

\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{da} = 2a - \frac{2k^2}{a^3}.
\end{equation}

Now look for critical points $a^*$ where that derivative is zero,

\begin{equation}
2a^* - \frac{2k^2}{a^{*3}} = 0,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
a^* = \pm \sqrt{k}.
\end{equation}

Substituting this back into our $b$ equation yields our optimal $b$ value $b^*$,
\begin{equation}
b^* = \frac{-k}{\pm\sqrt{k}} = \mp\sqrt{k}
\end{equation}
and hence a minimum $f$ value, $f^*$ of 
\begin{equation}
f^* = (\pm{\sqrt{k}})^2 + (\mp{\sqrt{k}})^2 = 2k
\end{equation}

Note: We have only demonstrated here this is a critical point - not that it is necessarily a minimum. To find the nature, we will use the second derivative test.

Find the second derivative
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 f}{da^2} = 2 + \frac{6k^2}{a^4}
\end{equation}

For any real value $a$, this will clearly be positive, hence we know the critical point must be a minimum.

For the special case $k = 16$, minimum values $(a^*, b^*) = (\pm 4, \mp 4)$ and minimum sum of squares $f^* = 32$.

Comment: I knew how to solve this problem, but I don't understand how finding that $a$ is a minimum value means the related value, $b$, is a minimum value as well.

Comment: For any value of $a$ there is only one value of $b$ that will satisfy $ab = -k$. By making the initial substitution, the resulting value of $a$ minimizes $f$ taking into account $a$'s effects on $f$, both explicit (the $a^2$ part) and implicit (via $a$'a effect on $b$).